# failing to login with passport-local

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to use passport-local on my authentication but the code is not executing as expected. I want It to redirect to my homepage after the user has been authenticated

I have tried the code on the documentation by not yielding any results

```
const express =  require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport =  require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const app = express();
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
// app.use(passport.initialize());

passport.serializeUser((user, cb) =>{
    cb(null, user.id)
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, cb) =>{
    User.findById(id, (err, user) =>{
        if(err){ return cb(err)}
        cb(null, user);
    });
});

const Schema = mongoose.Schema ;


const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
});
const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

passport.use(new LocalStrategy( 
    (username, password, done) =>{
        UserAll.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user){
            if(err){return done}
            if(!user){return done(nul, false)}
            if(user.password != password){
                return done(null, false);
            }
            return done(null, user);

        });
    }
));


app.get('/' , (req, res) =>{
    res.send('the home page');

});


app.get('/login', (req, res) =>{
    res.render('login');

});

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {failureRedirect: '/login'}), (req, res) =>{
    res.redirect('/');
    // console.log(req.body);
});


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/PassportLocalTest', {useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.connection.once('open', () =>{
    console.log('connected');

}).once('error', (error) =>{
    console.log('connection error ', error);
});


app.listen(3000, () =>{
    console.log('listening to port 3000');`enter code here`
});
```

The passport-local strategy is failing to redirect the user after the authentication process

Comment: You are declaring your user model as `User` but then running `UserAll.findOne` during login, is that an error translating to the question or could that be the problem?

Comment: thanks a lot on that part .. but even though I corrected from userAll to user it is still not redirecting to the homepage

Comment: Try to add some `console.log` statements both before and after the `User.findOne` line, this will at least check if it's reaching this code block. Does the page just hang or are you redirected back to the `/login` route?

Comment: I am redirected back to the /login page

Comment: Try setting the `failureFlash: true` flag in the options, this will show you the error it's encountered (you might need to add the `connect-flash` package to view this flash message).

Comment: I have tried to add the urlencodedParser on the app.post('/login', urlencodedParse, passport.authenticate('local' …….)  and it worked... after I added the body-parser middleware